# solve a differential equation with absolute value

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I wanna solve this form of equation:
x' = -A.x + B.|sin(100*pi*t)| 
and i use ode45 like this:

```
function find_x
t = 0:0.001:10;
x0 = 0;
R1 = 90000;
R2 = 1000;
C = 0.001;
[t,x]=ode45(@rhs, t , x0);

plot(t,x);

    function dxdt = rhs(t,x)
        dxdt = -(C/R1 + C/R2)*x + C/R1*abs(sin(100*pi*t)) ;
        %It's form is dx/dt = -A.x + B.U(t)
    end
end
```

but i think it give me the wrong answer.
actually, i get this equation from a problem "find output voltage form after a diode bridge and a capacitor" like this:
[image]

can anyone suggest to me a another way to solve it ? thanks.

Comment: This question is probably more suited for electronics.stackexchange.com. From the MATLAB perspective, it looks like you're using `ode45` correctly.

Comment: i don't know whether i use `abs(sin(100*pi*t))` is right or wrong.

Comment: One of the ways is to plow over the discontinuity like you have done. For other methods this question needs to be migrated to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is probably not the place to get help on electronics. However, I see one potential issue. You're trying to integrate very small values. Your parameters are "badly scaled." `C/R1` is about `1e-8`. It would be a good idea to use different units.

Comment: You'll at least want to do this to increase your integration tolerances: `opts = odeset('RelTol', 1e-12, 'AbsTol', 1e-12); [t,x]=ode45(@rhs, t , 0, opts);`. Note how the output changes when you do this (it may well not be what you want but it's different). This is a sign that the default tolerances were not sufficient. You have small parameters and high frequency oscillation and strong nonlinearity (`abs`).

Comment: @horchler: thanks u, it make my result look better :)

Comment: Are you sure you should have ratio of R and C and not product? Time constant of RC circuit is `RC`... Ripple will be smaller when C is bigger and/ or R is bigger - so you need their product not ratio. Where did you get your equation?

Comment: yeah, i knew my error, and I fixed like it Rasman's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really the place to solve this, and this takes me back to my signal & systems days, but basically your equations should have C as a divider...

Remember it's

```
I = C *dV/dt
```

Therefore if you have dV/dt on the RHS, you should expect to see 1/C on the LHS:

```
function khan
t = 0:0.001:10;
x0 = 0;
R1 = 90000;
R2 = 1000;
C = 0.001;
options = odeset('RelTol',1e-6,'AbsTol',1e-8);
[t,x]=ode45(@rhs, t , x0,options);

plot(t,x);

    function dxdt = rhs(t,x)
        dxdt = -(1/R1 + 1/R2)*x/C + 1/R1*abs(sin(100*pi*t))/C ;
        %It's form is dx/dt = -A.x + B.U(t)
    end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really think that function has a solution that looks like your plot? I know you don't. Consider what `ode45`'s default tolerances are and the magnitude of the the result. I'd suggest: `opts = odeset('RelTol',1e-6,'AbsTol',1e-9); [t,x]=ode45(@rhs, t , x0, opts);`.

Comment: @horchler... my bad as I thought the default tolerances were 1e-8 for both, while also thinking that the frequency was relatively small. Thank you and fixed. Attitude could be better though.

Comment: @Rasman: this result is what i expected for, thanks a lot.  I was wrong from the original equation :))

Comment: I have a new problem. Output voltage v is DC and i think it equal the rms of input (after mutiply (R10 + R11)/R11 = 91). But the fact is they have a ratio 10/9 between v*91 and Vrms. I try changing the value of R1, R2, and C, even the frequency, but the ratio 10/9 doesn't change. So what is this ratio ?

`plot(t,(R10+R11)/R11*x*10/9);
Y0 = 220; %Y0 is rms of the input V(s)
plot(t,Y0);`

[FIGURE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0eht72dfl75mk2a/ptvp.png)